# Why does Quaid shoot the soldier that frees him?

Tags: plot-explanation, total-recall-2012

In the 2012 version of *Total Recall*, when Quaid is being strapped into the chair to have his Hauser memories/personality re-implanted one of the soldiers is shown to cut Quaid's wrist restraints with some sort of laser. Quaid and the soldier then share a knowing glance.

Seconds later Quaid breaks free of his restraints, breaks this soldier's leg steals his gun, and eventually shoots everyone in the room including his rescuer.

Did I miss something, or is Quaid just incredibly ungrateful?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though your consfusion is understandable (since most of them are wearing masks and the scene is pretty fast), **you looked at the wrong soldier.**

Look again. One of the soldiers (Hammond) is the mysterious friend that helped Quaid earlier on. Quaid realizes it when he sees Hammond's eyes and that he's cutting his restraints. Hammond then *backs away* towards the camera and then another soldier takes his place and is about to inject Quaid. It's *this soldier's* leg that Quaid kicks.

Hammond then lunges at the robot and fights with it, and Quaid shoots the *robot* to help Hammond. But Hammond is then gunned down by a *soldier* (who's lying on the floor) with a machine gun once that soldier realizes that Hammond is helping Quaid. Quaid, who wasn't quick enough to prevent this, shoots *that* soldier dead, then goes over to Hammond, removes his mask and ruefully realizes that Hammond is dead too. Hammond sacrificed himself to help Quaid.

Comment: It does all happen fairly fast, but Walt's answer is accurate.

Comment: I like to think I'm more observant than most, but I did not pick that up even after several viewings. Thanks!